# How to find and replace word or character in paragraph using bash script?

Tags: bash

I want to write a script which take input as a paragraph. In that paragraph I want to find and replace a word or a character provide by the user and display the new paragraph with the changes.
I also want to count the specific word in a paragraph provided by user.

Answer (score 1):

Read the input of the user as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

read input # creates a variable $input with the users input until <enter>
```

To replace a string in the paragraph:

```
echo $input| sed 's/search-string/replace-string/g'
```

To count the words:

```
echo $input| wc -w
```

Comment: echo $input| wc -w count all the string. i want to count specific string like if input like "i am a bash bash bash programer" then give count for bash as 3..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Python script to do the task. I think Python is the easiest choice for doing these type of tasks (Although `bash` is mentioned, you can give it a try).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
input_string = raw_input('Give me an input: ')

if input_string:
    to_be_replaced = raw_input('Which word you want to replace? ')
    replaced_by_what = raw_input('To be replaced by the word: ')
    print input_string.replace(to_be_replaced, replaced_by_what)
    print '\n', to_be_replaced, 'occurs', input_string.count(to_be_replaced), 'times in input string'

else:
    print 'No input given..try again!!'
```